# NumberFormatException: Invalid int - String

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-fragments, parse-platform

I have received the below exception while trying to retrieve number from the number column on Parse - NumberFormatException: Invalid int

I want to retrieve number and then display the number in the TextView. I have been able to achieve this with strings, but is having difficulty with numbers.

Below is logcat message:

```
09-02 10:00:27.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1267): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-02 10:00:27.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1267): Process: com.dooba.beta, PID: 1267
09-02 10:00:27.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1267): java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "UserAge"
09-02 10:00:27.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
09-02 10:00:27.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:374)
09-02 10:00:27.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:365)
09-02 10:00:27.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
09-02 10:00:27.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at com.dooba.beta.Fragment1$6.done(Fragment1.java:371)
09-02 10:00:27.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at com.parse.FindCallback.internalDone(FindCallback.java:45)
09-02 10:00:27.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at com.parse.FindCallback.internalDone(FindCallback.java:31)
09-02 10:00:27.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at com.parse.Parse$5$1.run(Parse.java:891)
09-02 10:00:27.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-02 10:00:27.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-02 10:00:27.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-02 10:00:27.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
09-02 10:00:27.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-02 10:00:27.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-02 10:00:27.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
09-02 10:00:27.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
09-02 10:00:27.881: E/AndroidRuntime(1267):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Below is the code

```
query5.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {

                @Override
                public void done(List<ParseUser> objects,ParseException e) {

                    for(int i=0;i<objects.size();i++){
                        // Do whatever you need to extract object from "users"
                        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("User");
                        query.whereNotEqualTo("objectId", ParseUser.getCurrentUser()
                                .getObjectId());
                        // users with Gender = currentUser.Looking_Gender
                        query.whereEqualTo("Gender", userLookingGender);
                        // users with Looking_Gender = currentUser.Gender
                        query.whereEqualTo("Looking_Gender", userGender);
                        query.setLimit(1);
                        query.whereEqualTo("ActivityName", activityName);
                        query.whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo("UserAge", minimumAge);
                        query.whereLessThanOrEqualTo("UserAge", maximumAge);

                        mUserAgeRetrieved = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.userlistage);

                        String str = "UserAge";
                        int iage = Integer.parseInt(str);
                        mUserAgeRetrieved.setText(iage); 



                    }
        }//for loop
                });
```

Just for comparison, below is how I retrieve string:

```
mUserNameRetrieved.setText(objects.get(i).get("Name").toString());
```

"UserAge" refers to the number column in parse that I am calling to retrieve the number in it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `String str = "UserAge";int iage = Integer.parseInt(str);` == `int iage = Integer.parseInt("UserAge");` == `NumberFormatException` since `"UserAge"` is not a number! it is not a rocket science ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the point of this?

```
String str = "UserAge";
int iage = Integer.parseInt(str);
mUserAgeRetrieved.setText(iage);
```

Obviously it throws a NumberFormatException, because "UserAge" isn't a number! You're not retrieving any number from your ParseQuery here.

Edit:
Use mUserAgeRetrieved.setText(String.valueOf(objects.get(i).getInt("UserAge"))) to retrieve the number.

Comment: I felt I was doing something incorrectly since this code is not properly retrieving a number. the UserAge represents the UserAge column. I know It is not a number, but that column holds numbers in it.

Comment: You might just do it the same as you retrieve strings and call Integer.parseInt() on that string.

Comment: okay thanks. This is what I have worked around so far                         mUserAgeRetrieved.setText(objects.get(i).get(Integer.parseInt("UserAge")).toString()); 
but I can't exactly do that because get is looking for a string

Comment: This is the code I was trying before. It works fine if am retrieving a string, but the problem is that I am retrieving a number so either I have to convert the number into a string, or retrieve the number directly instead.

Comment: Use mUserAgeRetrieved.setText(String.valueOf(objects.get(i).getInt("UserAge")));

Comment: thank you for your prompt response. I receive the following error: - The method getInt(int) is undefined for the type List<ParseUser>

Answer (score 1):

you have to change this line:

```
String str = "UserAge";
```

to

```
 String str = mUserAgeRetrieved.getText();
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but then how would I refer to the UserAge column?